# How can I configure WSO2 ESB like Gateway to publish from WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

In WSO2 API Manager, I want to use an WSO2 ESB instance in local to publish API. I mean, I configure in /repository/conf/api-manager.xml an ESB instance like Gateway, like this:

```
<APIGateway>
<Environments>
    <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
        <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
        <Description> Description of environment</Description>

        <!--ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL-->
        <ServerURL>https://localhost:8243/services/</ServerURL>

        <!--Username>${admin.username}</Username-->
        <Username>admin</Username>

        <!--Password>${admin.password}</Password-->
        <Password>admin</Password>

        <!--GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint-->
        <GatewayEndpoint>http://localhost:8280,https://localhost:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
    </Environment>
</Environments>
<EnableGatewayKeyCache>true</EnableGatewayKeyCache>
<EnableGatewayResourceCache>true</EnableGatewayResourceCache>
<ClientDomainHeader>referer</ClientDomainHeader>
</APIGateway>
```

I followed this article https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publish+through+Multiple+API+Gateways and I just changed the configuration according to my ESB instance.

The problem is in API publisher, when I want to publish a new API I get follow error:

```
Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed
```

NOTE: I changed port of serviceURL from 9443 to 8243 because I couldn't show service list of ESB in my browser, and with 8243 I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a feature installation on ESB ?

By default WSO2 ESB  does not contain certain features that are required for it to serve as the gateway in this scenario. It is not possible to use ESB here, without a feature installation.

Therefore we recommend you to use an instance of WSO2 API Manager itself as the gateway.

The `HTTPS servlet transport port` of the Gateway needs to be given as the gateway's `<serverURL>`.

Comment: No, I haven't. ESB is a feature installation by default.

My <ServerURL> is not correct? I tired with 9443 (ESB port) as well, but I can not publish at all.